# laurent polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

A Laurent polynomial is a ”polynomial” in which negative as well as positive powers of the variable $x$ are allowed, for example, $p(x) = 7x^{-3} + 4x^{-2} + 4 + 2x$. Show that the set of Laurent polynomials with coefficients in a field $K$ forms a ring with identity. This ring is denoted by $K[x, x^{-1}]$. (If you prefer, you may take $K = \Bbb{R}$.) What are the units?

Comment: Which of the properties of a Ring are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\ K[x,x^{-1}]\, \cong\, K[x,y]/(xy-1)$